# M2E-Pro: 'M2E Tax Rate' still appearing after M2E-Pro uninstall

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and tried M2E-Pro v.5.0.3. but decided not to use it. After uninstalling M2E-Pro, in the .pdf-invoices a label called 'M2E Tax Rate' still appears and I cannot find, where it is taken from. The steps I used for uninstalling M2E-Pro were:

- deleting all tax rules and tax rates related to M2E using the Magento admin
- uninstalling M2E-Pro using Magento Connect Manager
- dropping all tables with the prefix 'm2epro_' and the table 'ess_config' from the database

I had an exchange with the M2E-Support but I only get standard answers that do not help me.

Please tell me where I could look for a 'hidden' entry in the database or something like that. It makes me wonder that the label 'M2E Tax Rate' only appears in the generated .pdf-invoice - nowhere else.

Thanks in advance,
mkr

Answer (score 0):

What they've done is create a product tax rate in your Magento system and you probably have it set to products and/or in your magento tax settings too.

Go to **Sales > Tax and Product Tax rules**

You should find the tax rate here.

If you remove it, do check your products in Magento...

Also go to **System > Configuration > Sales > Tax** and see if it has been applied here too.

Hope that helps,

Matt